# Make @RequestHeader hidden true & not required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

I have this post request method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "personnePhysique", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getRapportSolvabilitePPUsingPOST(
        @ApiParam(value = "rapportPP", required = true) @Valid @RequestHeader Map<String, String> apiHeader, @RequestBody RapportPP rapportPP)
        throws BusinessException {
    RapportPPDTO dto = mapper.convertValue(rapportPP, RapportPPDTO.class);
    String apiId = null;
    String apiPwd = null;
    /* Iterate over apiHeaders map */
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : apiHeader.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(ApiConstants.CB_API_USER_ID) && entry.getValue().equals(ApiConstants.CB_API_USER_PWD))
        {
            apiId = entry.getKey();
            apiPwd = entry.getValue();
        }
        System.out.println("Item : " + entry.getKey() + " Count : " + entry.getValue());
        System.out.println("apiId : " + apiId);
        System.out.println("apiPwd : " + apiPwd);
        
    }
    /* Iterate over apiHeaders map */
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream array = this.rapportSolvabiliteService.getRapportSolvabilitePhysique(dto, apiId, apiPwd);
        return toSubscribeContractModel(array, "rapportSolvabilite.pdf");
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        throw new BusinessException(500, message.getString(ApiConstants.TECHNICAL_ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY), e);
    }
}
```

As you can see, because @ApiParam required option is true, it makes @RequestHeader apiHeader required as well,
I want to know how can I make apiHeader hidden and optionnal, so it will not appear in my Swagger documentation, and keep my body (rapportPP) required only.

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to delete @ApiParam.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but If you delete @ApiParam, they both will be in default value (required & not hidden)

Answer (score 0):

I have just found that we can use @ApiParam on several fields:

```
@PostMapping(value = "personnePhysique", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getRapportSolvabilitePPUsingPOST(
        @ApiParam(value = "rapportPP", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody RapportPP rapportPP,
        @ApiParam(value = "apiHeader", required = false, hidden = true) @RequestHeader Map<String, String> apiHeader)
        throws BusinessException {
    RapportPPDTO dto = mapper.convertValue(rapportPP, RapportPPDTO.class);
    String apiId = null;
    String apiPwd = null;
    /* Iterate over apiHeaders map */
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : apiHeader.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(ApiConstants.CB_API_USER_ID) && entry.getValue().equals(ApiConstants.CB_API_USER_PWD))
        {
            apiId = entry.getKey();
            apiPwd = entry.getValue();
        }
        System.out.println("Item : " + entry.getKey() + " Count : " + entry.getValue());
        System.out.println("apiId : " + apiId);
        System.out.println("apiPwd : " + apiPwd);
        
    }
    /* Iterate over apiHeaders map */
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream array = this.rapportSolvabiliteService.getRapportSolvabilitePhysique(dto, apiId, apiPwd);
        return toSubscribeContractModel(array, "rapportSolvabilite.pdf");
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        throw new BusinessException(500, message.getString(ApiConstants.TECHNICAL_ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY), e);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, you can specify values for each one, like in this example:

- ApiHeader is hidden and not required
- rapportPP is not hidden and required

Thanks